# How to make a WPF TextBox use password characters?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, winforms, textbox, passwords

i need to set it it dynamicaliy..

Can i make password Box to as normal text-
i mean- user could see the text what he entered.???

its for-> i need  to use same control for " password sesion" and also the "item count entering" session ..??

Comment: So, after reading all answers (which are effectively [XY-problem-tailored](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)) and, at the risk of repeating the question, **how does one make a WPF TextBox use password characters**?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You have to use `PasswordBox` instead of `TextBox`:

```
<PasswordBox Height="42" Width="200"  Margin="22,28,28,0" 
         Name="passwordBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
         Background="LightBlue" Foreground="DarkBlue" 
         MaxLength="25" PasswordChar="*" 
         />
```

Answer (score 22):

There's a new control in WPF designed for passwords, it's called `PasswordBox`. You should use that instead of a `TextBox` if you need to mask the input.

[Here's a brief article about it.](http://pstaev.blogspot.com/2007/01/password-textbox-in-wpf.html) To retrieve the value that was entered, use the *Password* property.

**EDIT**: You've pretty much asked a new question - ***how can you unmask the text in a WPF PasswordBox***? To the best of my knowledge you can't, though you could of course display it in a regular TextBox on demand by getting the value of the password from `PasswordBox.Password`

Databinding to a `PasswordBox` isn't possible without a custom helper class - though this would reduce the increased security offered by the new `PasswordBox` control ([as described here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/7ca97b60-2d8e-4a27-8c5b-b8d5d7370a5e/)). With that considered, [this article includes a section on creating a helper class](http://www.wpftutorial.net/PasswordBox.html) that allows you to databind to a `PasswordBox`.

Answer (score 7):

Or use 'password font'. A font that shows all characters as dots. Remember to disable cut and copy clipboard functions.

Comment: can you add some link too?

Answer (score 2):

There are also custom implementations of `PasswordBox` which you can alter for your needs, see 
[this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpf_enhanced_passwordbox.aspx). You also can extend this which is not possible with the `PasswordBox` because its a sealed class.