# How to achieve (*) sign pattern in WPF textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I want to use WPF Textbox and want (*) sign as the mask (password char) of text entered, something like password box but not the password box as it's not MVVM Friendly and not matching business logic.

Even I saw Change fonts but I guess there should be a way of doing it.

my question is similar to [How to make a WPF TextBox use password characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792764/how-to-make-a-wpf-textbox-use-password-characters)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would a password field not match your business logic, if that is exactly what you're asking for in your question?

Comment: how can an input control for a text not match a business logic? Why and how is a user control not 'MVVM friendly'? Password inputs know the password, they just hide them.

Comment: @silkfire, I have 4 textbox just like OTP control, it should accept only numeric value and if it's numeric focus should move to next textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite sure to the best of my knowledge that WPF Textboxes do not support masked characters in this sense. As stated in the comments I don't completely understand the stance on not just using a PasswordBox which would support PassChar. I've read about a certain MaskedTextbox class but have not experimented enough with it to know if that's what's best. I'd recommended revisiting the idea of just using a PasswordBox.